# Who portrayed the male newscaster in the movie Imposter?

Tags: philip-k-dick

At the end of Dimension Films' *[Impostor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_(2001_film))* a newscaster is announcing the climactic event on television. He looks and sounds exactly like *Voyager's* Harry Kim.

Is this announcer Garrett Wang?

[image: News announcement in Imposter]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's **Burt Bulos**, listed as [Newscaster #3](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0160399/fullcredits) in the IMDB credits.

You can see a video clip of him here; https://www.imdb.com/videoplayer/vi235583769 on daytime TV

[image]